# The legitimacy of a deposed Government in international law?

Tags: international-law, revolutions

Is a government overthrown by a coup d'état or revolution legitimate under international law?Is the interim government also, correspondingly, legitimate? Are there juristic documents on this, or is it essentially a political issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141310/discussion-between-uberhaxed-and-joe-w).

Answer (score 4):

The legitimacy of a deposed Government (and the legitamacy of the new government for that matter) is largely a decision for other nations to decide as it will result in that nation's continued diplomatic relations with the new government.  For example, several nations officially do not recognize Nicolás Maduro's 2018 election victory was legitimate and thus have refused to recognize the current government.  Argentina, Chile, Colombia, Brazil, Canada, Germany, France and the United States, have refused to recognize Maduro, as well as the Organization of American States (OAS) which includes among member states and observer states all of the aforementioned states save for Germany (France is allowed observer status as it still has territorial holdings in the Americas).  It should be noted that while Venezuela withdrew it's member status from the OAS, the nation's national assembly has since annulled it's withdrawal and designated a special envoy to the OAS.

Conversely several nations have recognized Maduro as the legitimate winner of the 2018 election including Cuba, China, Russia, Turkey, and Iran, although this might have less close relations, specifically China and Turkey which have strong economical and military ties with many of the nations that do not recognize Maduro (China notably has scaled back it's financial relations with Venezuala, reportedly due to pressure from America, Germany, and France, who have significant economic ties to China.).